# How to set up the connection string for pyodbc on Linux?

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, odbc

I have the following code which works fine.

```
import pyodbc
CONNECTION_STRING="""Driver=ODBC Driver for MS SQL Server 17;
                     Server=myserver.company.com;
                     Database=MyDB;
                     UID=....;
                     PWD=....;"""
connection = pyodbc.connect(CONNECTION_STRING)
```

Now I need to change to an AD/Windows account of my company. I tried

```
CONNECTION_STRING="""Driver=ODBC Driver for MS SQL Server 17;
                     Server=myserver.company.com;
                     Database=MyDB;
                     Encrypt=YES;TrustServerCertificate=YES""""
```

But it doesn't work?

> InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")

And

```
CONNECTION_STRING="""Driver=ODBC Driver for MS SQL Server 17;
                     Server=myserver.company.com;
                     Database=MyDB;
                     Trusted_Connection=yes"""
```

got error of

> Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSPI Provider: No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:3204410) (851968) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Aside... are you really using `ODBC Driver for MS SQL Server 17`? What are the actual connection string parameters?

Comment: For a first pass with local Active Directory authentication (assuming you already have Kerberous setup) have you tried using `Trusted_Connection=yes;` in your connection string yet? Beware that this is different than Azure Active Directory.

Comment: I tried `Trusted_Connection=yes`. It got a different error. The question has been updated.

Comment: These connection strings are the actually ones. I just replaced the server, db, UID and password values.

Comment: You must configure Kerberos per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/using-integrated-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Sounds like you haven;t set up Kerberos properly. `Trusted_Connection=yes` uses Kerberos, `Encrypt=yes` is for SSL encryption, `TrustServerCertificate=yes` is to ignore SSL errors (which is inadvisable)